x axis scroll on the mobile screen
   .navigation {
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    right: -300px;
    width: 200px;

    display: flex;
    padding-top: 40px;
    background-color:  #071e244b ;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: left;
    transition: right 0.3s ease-in-out;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
    backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
   }

  .navigation.open {
   right: 0;
   }``

I use the hamburger button on the right side of the header when the screen size is less than 768 px. On clicking hamburger, the navigation bar translates from -200 px to 0 px. In a desktop window, even if the screen width is much smaller than 768px, no x axis scrolls while the navigation bar is at -200px. but on the mobile screen the scroll to the x axis and can see the navigation bar at -200px. How to prevent the x scroll on mobile screens
I tried css property like overflox-x:hidden on the body element. Then I use add eventListner resize to hide overflow x on the body
body{
overflow-x: hidden !important;
overflow-y: auto !important;
}


Please provide a runnable snippet. It’s hard debugging part code/part verbal description. This link should help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

You have set right property to -300px instead of -200px. I believe that is the problem.
Here is a snippet for you to test corrected version:


document.querySelector("#nav-button").addEventListener("click", ()=> {


document.querySelector("#navigation").classList.toggle("open")

})
#container{
width:100%;
height:100%;

}

#navigation{
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px; /* i think this blank space is for heading */
    right: -200px;
    width: 200px;
    display: flex;
    padding-top: 40px;
    background-color:  #071e244b ;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: left;
    transition: right 0.3s ease-in-out;
    height: 100vh;

}



  #navigation.open {
   right: 0;
   }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
<button id="nav-button">Open Navigation</button>

<nav id="navigation"></nav>


</div>
    
</body>
</html>



